# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame - don't understand ist

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I know this topic has been discussed a lot and I am so sorry, that I stil dont't find the sulution, even the difference between a view and a copy is easy to understand (in other languages)

```
def hole_aktienkurse_und_berechne_hist_einstandspreis(index, start_date, end_date):
    df_history = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols=index, start=start_date, end=end_date)
    df_history['HistEK'] = df_history['Adj Close']
    df_only_trd_index = df_group_trade.loc[index].copy()

    for i_hst, r_hst in df_history.iterrows():
        df_bis = df_only_trd_index[(df_only_trd_index['DateClose']<=i_hst) & (df_only_trd_index['OpenPos']==0)].copy()
        
        # here comes the part what causes the trouble:
        df_history.loc[i_hst]['HistEK'] = df_history.loc[i_hst]['Adj Close'] - df_bis['Total'].sum()/100.0
    return df_history
```

I think I tried nearly everithing, but I don't get it. python is not easy when it comes to this topic.

Comment: Between it's a warning not an error so you can ignore it

Comment: how can I avoid the warning, it irritates me a lot in python notebook because it's in red. I probably do somethin wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to specify bow index and column in `.loc` you have to put all together otherwise the annoying message relative to views appears.

```
df_history.loc[i_hst, 'HistEK'] = df_history.loc[i_hst, 'Adj Close'] - df_bis['Total'].sum()/100.0
```

Look the examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: thank you soooooooooo much. realy, you saved my day